# Refresh page automatically after submitting form

Tags: php, html

After I submit my data from form I don't see it immediate on my screen, I have to refresh it via browser refresh button.

```
<form action="" method="post">  

<input type="submit" name="submit"  >
```

I was using the `setTimeout` function but it gave me lot of issues in submitting to the database and retrieving from it. I could not debug it properly, and so I removed this function. Without `setTimeout`, I am able to store in the database and retrieve via the refresh button. But how do I make it immediately auto refresh?

Comment: first ,put your b connection here , second , you can use function that return information from your db , then , after your inserting query , call function again!

Comment: Learn more more more... This is not a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

i have done with the help of jquery and ajax without refresh and page loading
html file with ajax

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#sub").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                            url: 'dbadd.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {naam:$("#nm").val()},
                            success:function(response){
                                $("#d1").html(response)
                            }
                        });
            });

        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <form method="post">  
        Name : <input type="text" id="nm" name="name">
        <div id="d1"></div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="sub" value="submit">
    </form>
    </html>
```

php file : adddb.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("empl",$con);
    $q=mysql_query("insert into emp(name) values ('".$_POST['naam']."')");
    $qq=mysql_query("select name from emp where name='".$_POST['naam']."'");
    while ($data=mysql_fetch_object($qq)) {
        echo $data->name;

    }
?>
```

Comment: Any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For refresh page use this code:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV ='Refresh' Content ='0; URL =/'>
```

You can use like this end of your code:

```
<?php echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV ='Refresh' Content ='0; URL =/'>"; ?>
```

Comment: you mean inside form action part? or separate

Comment: end of your php code. when your data stored in database successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Set your action as:
`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`

and it will do the trick.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
```

Action is the directive that trigger what to do with the data. If you don't specify it how is the browser supposed to do anithing?

Comment: Any other solution? as I tried this and it does not refresh my page with latest database entries made. It still shows me page with before submit values.